# Como fazer soma em javascript

Tags: javascript

Dentro de uma função introduzi este código e por algum motivo não esta a somar.

```
var total = (currentUser.profile.hp + currentUser.profile.attack + currentUser.profile.luck) / 3;
```

a multiplicação funciona perfeitamente  com o caracter '*'

Comment: Os valores são todos numéricos? Pode tentar converter para número assim: `var total = (Number(currentUser.profile.hp) + .....)`

Comment: multiplicação funciona

Comment: se multiplicação funciona, soma também deve, a não ser que os valores não forem numéricos, porque ai irá tentar concatenar, tente converter todos usando `Number`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provavelmente algum deles é `string` e não um `Number`, veja a diferença:

```js
//Com string
var currentUser = {
    profile: { hp: "300", attack: 100, luck: 10 }
};

console.log(currentUser.profile.hp + currentUser.profile.attack + currentUser.profile.luck);

//Com Number/sem string:
currentUser = {
    profile: { hp: 300, attack: 100, luck: 10 }
};

console.log(currentUser.profile.hp + currentUser.profile.attack + currentUser.profile.luck);
```

Desta forma o sinal de `+` irá concatenar porque o primeiro é uma `string`, claro que o sinal de  multiplicação funciona `*`, pois ele **não** é usado para outras operações em JavaScript, como concatenar, ele é só usado para operações matemáticas veja:

```js
var currentUser = {
    profile: { hp: "300", attack: 100, luck: 10 }
};

var total = currentUser.profile.hp * currentUser.profile.attack * currentUser.profile.luck; 

console.log(total);
```

---

Uma possível solução é colocar um `1 *` na frente:

```js
var total = (1 * "10") + (1 * "11");

console.log(total);
```

Ou usar `Number`

```js
var total = Number("10") + Number("11");

console.log(total);
```

### Facilitando

Para facilitar tudo isso você pode criar uma função só para somar que pega os argumentos e os converte/cast:

```js
function Somar(){
    var soma = 0;

    for (var i = arguments.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        soma += Number(arguments[i]);
    }

    return soma;
}

var currentUser = {
    profile: { hp: "300", attack: 100, luck: 10 }
};

var total = Somar(currentUser.profile.hp, currentUser.profile.attack, currentUser.profile.luck) / 3;

console.log(total);
```